# asp.net 3.5 repeater: use dataitem in codebehind function

Tags: asp.net, repeater

normally when i want to dislplay the value of a dataitem in a repeater, i use this:

```
<%#Eval("contact") %>
```

but now i want to transform the value of this field (contact) in a codebehind function, so i tried this:

```
<%= ShowcontactInfo(Eval("Contact")) %>
```

but then i get the exception (at runtime):

**Databinding methods such as Eval(), XPath(), and Bind() can only be used in the context of a databound control.**

What can i do?

Michel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can't you do it like this? : `<%# ShowcontactInfo(Eval("Contact")) %>`

Answer (score 4):

Does this not work?

```
<%# ShowcontactInfo(Eval("Contact")) %>
```

Note that `Eval` returns an object, so your method `ShowcontactInfo` either needs to aceept an object, or you need to use a cast.

`<%=` is a shortcut for Response.Write, and is not the same as thnhe databinding syntax `<%#`

Comment: +1 for the 'object' info, and the answer is also correct, but Klaus was a little faster (amazing, 2 answers in 1 minute) so i'll give him the mark-as-answer.